# Select cells in Excel, convert to Markdown, copy to clipboard

Tags: markdown, microsoft-excel, plug-in

Is there a software (an Excel plugin, Macro, ...) or any workaround to select table cells in an Excel Sheet, and to convert the selected cells to Markdown-Table Code, perhaps by copying it to the Clipboard.

The workflow should be similar to the [MarkdownTableMaker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdowntablemaker/cofkbgfmijanlcdooemafafokhhaeold?hl=en) Google-Spreadsheets Add-On (see screenshots there), but without need to upload anything to Google Drive (this is important when the user does not have a google account)

Can run on any OS, can cost anything.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that this could be done reasonably simply using [XL-Wings](https://www.xlwings.org/) which is an Excel plug-in that allows you to program in python within Excel.

You can add a button to run your python code and there is a function, *(strangely enough called `selection`)*, to return the selected cells, there are then lots of python libraries for preparing various flavors of markdown.